# Uploading third party libraries on apache and change permissions

Tags: javascript, apache, ubuntu, file-permissions

I am running an apache server on ubuntu. Whenever I upload a new third-party javascript library with `sftp` into the `www` folder, I noticed I need to change permissions of all `.js` and `.css` before it can be accessed by other files. I am usually finding myself doing `chmod o+rw` or `chmod o+x` on the folders and individual files. This is cumbersome as most of these libraries have recursive folders.

What is the proper (quick) way to do this, and one which does not compromise security?

Answer (score 0):

You should change owner of files, not allow everyone to access them. 
on ubuntu apache operates under user www-data.

```
chown -R www-data your_domain_folder
```

It will change owners recursively starting from your_domain_folder.
It will set only owner user, owner group will remain the same.

You can also set permission recursively with `chmod -R`

Comment: When I issue the command this is what it says: `chmod: invalid mode: www-data`